# Вывод изображения из файла на PHP

Tags: php

Есть изображение: *.png, нужно вывести изображение с помощью PHP...
P.s. Не `echo("<img src="*.png">");`, А именно изображение, что-бы как-бы этот php файл как-бы был изображением...

Comment: и в чем ваша проблема? [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php) найти не можете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Рабочий вариант:

```
 <?php          
      $image_url = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png';
      $image_info = getimagesize($image_url);   

      header('Content-type: ' . $image_info['mime']);

      readfile($image_url);      
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще это реализовывается с помощью стандартной библиотеки GD. Если нужно просто загрузить и вывести, то можно сделать так:

```
`<?php
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('1.jpg');
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
?>`
```

Comment: Просто readfile()